# Assigning values to an independent char array from a file

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to create an independent char array with date information, so I can sort it later with the other variables. The array for quantity and sold work as desired, but I am getting the following error in line 66 (item_date[i]=date;) : error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'. Does anybody know how I can fix this? Thanks

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define output_bit 1

struct soldItems{
        char date[10];
        int idNum;
        double quantity;
        double sold;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int n=1369;
        soldItems aItem[n];
        char filename[100] = "project.txt";
        double *item_quantity=new double[n];
        double *item_sold=new double[n];
        char *item_date=new char[n];


        FILE *fp;
        char header[100];

        double quantity, sold;
        int idNum;
        char date[10];

        char date_s[10],idNum_s[10], quantity_s[10], sold_s[10];
        int i=0;


        fp=fopen(filename, "r"); 



        if(!fp)
                perror("Double-check your input file");

        if(!feof(fp))
        {
                fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s\n", date_s, idNum_s,
                quantity_s, sold_s);
        }

        while(!feof(fp))
        {
                fscanf(fp, "%s %10d %lf %lf\n",
                date, &idNum, &quantity, &sold);


                strcpy(aItem[i].date, date);
                aItem[i].idNum = idNum;
                aItem[i].quantity = quantity;
                aItem[i].sold = sold;



                item_quantity[i]=quantity;
                item_sold[i]=sold;
                item_date[i]=date;
                i++;
        }

        fclose(fp); 

        if (output_bit) 
        { 
                cout<<"The item information is written in a structure array: \n"<<endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `item_date[i]=date;` is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `date` is of type `char*`, while `item_date[i]` is of type `char`. You're trying to load a string into a character, and that's where your error is. If, however, you want to declare `item_date` as an array of strings, you should declare it like this:

```
char **item_date = new char*[n];
```

This creates an array of `n` strings, each length 10. If you desire a different length, replace the 10 with something else.

Also, since you're programming in C++, I would advise you to use C++ strings, instead of C-style strings (arrays of chars).

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to save your strings, you can't do this

```
item_date[i]=date;
```

because here you are assigning a string (or char array) to char (one symbol like 'a').
You must change the `item_date` definition to this:

```
char **item_date = new char*[n];
```

Then in while loop:

```
item_date[i] = new char[size]; //size for you is 10
```

and in loop copy every value from date to item_date[i]

```
for(int j = 0; j< size; ++j){
   item_date[i][j] = date[j];
}
```

And everything should work.